# How can I list all modified files by an author between a commit range but only with the last thing that happened to the file in Git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

The command:

```
 git log --oneline --name-status 
         --author=$AUTHOR $COMMIT_RANGE | grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5} ' 
         | sort | uniq | cat -n
```

Returns a list of the files modified by an author between a range of commits with the status e.g. `M` for modified.

```
 1  M   a_file
 2  M   another_file
 3  M   file
 4  D   file
```

How can I show only the last thing that happened to the file `file`, e.g. here it was deleted (`D`)?

I don't want to see the previous modifications to the file (i.e. the `M`), only the last thing that happened in that range of commits.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Just adding `|tail -1` would be the obvious answer, but that will drop also `a_file` and `another_file`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @VonC What I want is to list all files modified between the commit range, but list each file only once with its last modification type (A, M, D, R, etc...)

Comment: Arne's answer does that, no?

Comment: @VonC No it doesn't, e.g. if I have a file which was modified (`M`) in one commit and added in an earlier commit (`A`) , I get them both, I only want to list the one line with the modified `--name-status`

Comment: Does uniq -f 1,2 work?

Comment: `uniq -f 1,2` gives `uniq: illegal field skip value: 1,2`, maybe because I am on an OS X machine?

Comment: I have found a way to do what I need. I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command I ended up with which works for me:

```
git log --oneline --name-status --author=$AUTHOR $COMMIT_RANGE | \
 grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5}' | cat -n | sed -e 's/     / /g' | sed -e 's/^  *//g' | \
 sort -k 3,3 -k 1n,1n | uniq -f 2 | sed -e 's/^[0-9]\{1,\} //' | cat -n
```

Where `$AUTHOR` is the author name and $COMMIT_RANGE is a range of commits in the form `OLDER_COMMIT_SHA1..NEWER_COMMIT_SHA1` (HEAD can be used too for NEWER_COMMIT_SHA1).

Command explanation:

1. First after removing the unwanted lines from the `git log` output with `grep -vE`, I number each line with `cat -n`;
2. I remove the TAB `git` inserts when using `--name-status` and the initial spaces inserted by `cat -n` with `sed -e 's/     / /g' | sed -e 's/^  *//g'`;
3. Then I sort by the **third column** first so I have the same filenames adjacent line by line (I sort by filename); after that I sort by the **first column** numerically (the `cat -n` result). This way I keep the first occurrence of the filename which is the one I'm interesting in;
4. After that it's time to keep the unique rows ignoring the first 2 columns (therefore only compare the filenames). This way `uniq` will return the first occurrence of a new filename first an will not repeat the other occurrences of the same filename; but at the same time the first filename for each 'group' is the one I'm interested in because it has the last `--name-status` flag I'm interested in and it tells me what's the last thing that happened on that file (was it a modification? A deletion? etc...);
5. Then I just remove the count because I need to recount the remaining rows after the `uniq` command and count again.

I want to thank `codeWizard`, `Arne` and `VonC` for the `uniq -f` advice which helped me to work out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want to do:

```
git log --oneline 
        --name-status 
        --author=$AUTHOR $COMMIT_RANGE 
        | grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5} ' | sort -r | uniq -f 1 |  head -1
```

What have i modified:

#### `sort -r`

reverse the sorting so the result will printed in reverse order

#### `head -1`

Take the first line of the result

#### `uniq -f 1`

Get the `uniq` values skipping the first row which is the counter so it cant be unique.

Comment: I don't need the first line only, I need to list each modified file between the commit range only once with its last modification type (--name-status)

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak `uniq` to look only at a certain field:

```
git log --oneline --name-status 
         --author=$AUTHOR $COMMIT_RANGE | grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5} ' 
         | sort -r | uniq -f 1 | tac | cat -n
```

I used `tac` as well to reverse the output again. You can leave it out though. Also it's a GNU utility which you won't find on BSD / OS X machines.

Comment: Is `tac` available in OS X through `MacPorts`?

Comment: `brew` and `port` both provide `coreutils` as a package, which provides either `tac` or `gtac` -- mostly the GNU utilities will be prefixed with a `g`.