# Using Git on Windows, how can I create reports that show modified files, commit messages, author and date

Tags: windows, git

What I am ideally after, is a solution that will allow me to build a report on who has touched what files, and what was changed, over time. So among other things, it can be used as a basis for reports on what work was done.

I've looked at many solutions, including 
[How can I list all modified files by an author between a commit range but only with the last thing that happened to the file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650270/how-can-i-list-all-modified-files-by-an-author-between-a-commit-range-but-only-w)

But the solutions all require *nix environments, we run ours on Windows.

I've tried the following which partly gives what I am looking for, in an exported file.

Ideally, I'd like the following, not necessarily in that order, on one line, or multiple as long as I can in the exported file, i can have each output on 1 line, rather than spanning.

```
File, author, commit, commit message, date.
report.rdl, user, hash, added this file, 2016-10-08
```

I can obtain parts of it using.

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:\"%h\";\"%cd\";\"%an\";\"%s\" --no-merges --since=1.weeks
```

Which gives the hash, date, user, and commit message, but I have no way of seeing which files were affected.

Can this be solved by using more verbose commit message, sure, but id like not to have to rely on that.

Alternatively, can something different be done.

Using the code supplied by LeGEC

```
git log --date=short --name-only --pretty=format:\"%h\";\"%cd\";\"%an\";\"%s\" --since=1.weeks --author=username --no-merges > output.txt
```

I get the following format:

```
"b60f1f6";"2016-10-12";"username";"Changed package PackageName.dtsx to also handle staging data via merge."
Packages/PackageName.dtsx
"2b1ddde";"2016-10-11";"username";"Hiding the A1 category, adding category A2 and A3."
Reports/CatReport.rdl
```

The issue arises when there are multipe files on a commit.

```
"b60f1f6";"2016-10-12";"username";"Changed package PackageName.dtsx to also handle staging data via merge."
Packages/PackageName.dtsx
"2b1ddde";"2016-10-11";"username";"Hiding the A1 category, adding category A2 and A3."
Reports/CatReport.rdl
Reports/CatReport1.rdl
```

So I realize, I probably can't do what I am trying to do, will have to come up with a different solution to creating work reports.

Ideally, it would be the following output:

```
"b60f1f6";"2016-10-12";"username";"Changed package PackageName.dtsx to also handle staging data via merge."
Packages/PackageName.dtsx
"2b1ddde";"2016-10-11";"username";"Hiding the A1 category, adding category A2 and A3."
Reports/CatReport.rdl
"2b1ddde";"2016-10-11";"username";"Hiding the A1 category, adding category A2 and A3."    
Reports/CatReport1.rdl
```

Ie, a line for each file in a commit.

Comment: `git log -1 <commit> --oneline --name-only | sed 1d` can list the changed files of this commit. `--name-status` can be used instead if you want to know the file status.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but AFAIK sed is *nix, not windows. 

Also, this would require i loop through each commit, rather than just getting a complete list.

Comment: @Tommy : for using satndard *nix tools on windows, have you ever tried cygwin ?

Comment: @LeGEC I have, however, installing these tools on a gitserver is not an unfortunately not an option. Which is why I was looking for a windows only solution.

Comment: @Tommy I wonder where you run `git log`. I use git-for-windows. Its MINGW64 supports the commands including `sed`. PowerShell is another option.

Comment: @ElpieKay I run it either in command prompt or the git admin promt

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--name-only` option (try also the `--name-status` option) :

```
git log --date=short --name-only --pretty=format:\"%h\";\"%...
```

---

The man page for git log (`git help log`) says :

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Shows the commit logs.
>
> The command takes options applicable to the git rev-list command to control what is shown and how, **and options applicable to
>   the
>   git diff-* commands** to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.

If you scroll through the (many) pages of options, you can find the section :

> COMMON DIFF OPTIONS
>
> -p, -u, --patch
>   Generate patch (see section on generating patches).
>
> [etc...]

with the (many) options you can use to display info on the diff introduced by each commit.